# sbt.ResolveException: download failed: org.scalaz#scalaz- core_2.9.2;6.0.4 while installing Apache Spark 0.8.1 on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, sbt, apache-spark

I'm trying to install Apache Spark on a freshly installed Ubuntu VMWare virtual machine as described in http://bigdatastatistics.blogspot.com/2013/11/installing-apache-spark-on-ubuntu-1204.html.

Everything seems to run fine until I try to actually install Spark.

```
$ sbt/sbt assembly
...
[error] (plugins/*:update) sbt.ResolveException: download failed: org.scalaz#scalaz-
core_2.9.2;6.0.4!scalaz-core_2.9.2.jar
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

I don't really know much about Scala or SBT, so if you can help me figure out what went wrong here, I'd really appreciate it.

Ubuntu version: 12.04.3 (32 bit)
Hadoop version: 1.2.1
Spark version: 0.8.1
Scala version: 2.10.3

Comment: Does your VMWare virtual machine have an internet connection?  Usually these errors are caused when sbt can't download a JAR from a repository.

Comment: It does have an internet connection - I was able to download other files. Is it perhaps trying to download an older version and not finding the repo? (If so, what files should I look at / update?)

Comment: think some troubles with versions (of dependencies / sbt); btw, did not noticed scalaz dependencies in a spark project:
https://github.com/apache/incubator-spark/blob/master/project/SparkBuild.scala try to download it again? what is your sbt version?

Comment: i'm using spark 0.8.0 so the sbt is version 0.12.4 (in build.properties, same directory as project/plugins.sbt)